# getting the selected column value from the datagrid and opening the particular form

Tags: c#, winforms

Thanks for the previous replies. I am working on `Windows Form`, and on Datagrid. I want something for editing so I have decided it with the help of context menu strip.
I want to know, how to get the selected column value
if the selected column is 1 then open form1
and if column2 is selected and contextmenu is clicked then open form2 how to get the column number and provide it in the if condition

I am working on this

```
       label1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();
```

but this code doesnt tranfers it gives the selected cell values.
how to determine which column is selected and put that in the if condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
       // open form1
    }
    else if (....)
    {
       // open form 2
    }
}
```

Comment: This returns the first cell of the first selected row.

Comment: sir i want in if loop. that if the first column's any cell is selected then open form1 and if second column's anycell is selected then open form2 if this possible?

Comment: by your code i have to select the whole row.. i dont want that i have a cell select option... if the cell is in column1 then open form 1 and if the cell is in column2 open form2

Comment: See my edit, you need to use the CellClick event to get the cell index.

Comment: sir when i click in the cell is directly opens the form if i want to use contextmenustrip this is not happening how to do that?

Comment: Inside the `if` create the `ContextMenuStrip` and then add an event to capture the selection.

Comment: sir one more thing please can you answer.. if i transfer the text from datagridview to a new form then can i pass the data from that  to the cell which i have selected?

Comment: You mean to pass the data of the form back to the original cell?